# Azure Webjob - OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error

Tags: java, azure-webjobs

I am facing "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error in azure webjob when I am trying to read JSON data (approx 50 mb) which is coming in a single line from an API.

While I am trying to optimize the code by reading small part of data at once and then processing the data. I would like to know if there is any way to increase heap size in azure?

I faced same issue in my local machine as well, adding -Xms512m -Xmx1024m arguments to eclipse run configuration fixed the problem, but adding same to web job batch file command didn't work.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar jarfilename.jar
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to increase heap size in azure.

Edit: I am using Premium 1 Medium app service plan.

I checked app service plan memory usage as well it didn't exceed 40%

Comment: Did you manage to use the 100% memory available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to assign 1024 MB to max heap only after changing server to 64 bit, I found 32 bit systems in azure has restriction where we can't commit more than 512 MB to max heap.

Answer (score 1):

What determines how much memory you can use is the App Service Plan that your Web App runs under. You're not specifying what Plan you are using now, but try scaling up to a higher tier.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ for details.

Comment: I am using P 1 medium app service plan, I believe it got 3 gig memory and I even checked app service plan memory usage it didn't exceed 40 %

Comment: P1 has 1.75. Try briefly switching to P2 just to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried p2 as well but it didn't work, only after switching server to 64 bit i am able to add 1024MB heap size and run the webjob successfully, seems for 32 bit system in azure 512 MB is the max Heap we can commit.

Answer (score 0):

My api-app (spring-boot) is S3-standard having 4core and 7GB ram, yet application was throwing java heap space error. Tried various way to set custom heap-size but was no luck. So then I setup application-settings (platform is 64 bit) -> app settings variable  as _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xmx4096m -Xms1512m

I can see initial heap is increased. :)